# Having Troubles with a Python Script

Tags: python

I've used this script before and had no problem but now when I try and run it I either get unsupported audio format or file not found.

```
import bpy

#Iterate through however many bars you want
for i in range(0, 64):
    #Add a plane and set it's origin to one of its edges
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location = ((i + (i*0.5)), 0, 0))
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = bpy.context.active_object.location
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.y -= 1
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')

    #Scale the plane on the x and y axis, then apply the transformation
    bpy.context.active_object.scale.x = 0.5
    bpy.context.active_object.scale.y = 20
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)

    #Insert a scaling keyframe and lock the x and z axis
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Scaling')
    bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves[0].lock = True
    bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves[2].lock = True

    #Set the window context to the graph editor
    bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'

    #Expression to determine the frequency range of the bars
    l = i**2 + 20
    h = (i+1)**2 + 20

    print(str(i) + ' ' + str(l) + ' ' + str(h))

    #Bake that range of frequencies to the current plane (along the y axis)
    bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r'/home/tyrone/Downloads/BAD BAWI.wav', low = (l), high = (h))

    #Lock the y axis
    bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves[1].lock = True
```

This is the script I'm trying to run in ubuntu but the only difference is the file path, and also the only problem I seem to be having. Other then possibly not having ffmpeg working with blender properly in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've tried your script and works for me!
I'm on ubuntu as well, maybe see if libwavpack1 is installed?